# Save Xml document in Web-Method in serverpath

Tags: asp.net, web-services

How to save XML document in web method in server path in asp.net?

```
XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
return ds.GetXml();

string _XMLFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Data\error1.xml");
ds.WriteXml(_XMLFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
doc.Save(_XMLFileName)
```

Comment: i can't get this line HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: Where exactly in your asp.net app is that line of code? which event? which class?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments, can you try using `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`. Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).

In your case it would be

```
string _XMLFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data/error1.xml");
```

`HostingEnvironment` maps path relative to your hosting location, so you will need to provide `~` for root location. In the example, the file will be inside your root directory of application, under `App_Data/Data` folder.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it at the moment..

```
 Dim path As String
  path = Server.MapPath("nameOfXMLDoc.xml")
  Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
  doc.Load(path)
```

And it works for me.. found the answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165438/Getting-XML-Data-from-Webservice-to-Infopath